# plasmashell doesn't start at all

Tags: arch-linux, plasma

It's been April, 1st, and this time Judd and Aaron had a huge impact on my Ryzen 7 machine:

```
kstart5 plasmashell
Omitting both --window and --windowclass arguments is not recommended
[miranda1@arch ~]$ org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine
**org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine
org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine
org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine
org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine
org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine
org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine
org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine
org.kde.plasma: Unable to load "Declarative widget" ScriptEngine**
file:///usr/share/plasma/shells/org.kde.plasma.desktop/contents/views/Desktop.qml:38:5: QML Connections: Implicitly defined onFoo properties in Connections are deprecated. Use this syntax instead: function onFoo(<arguments>) { ... }
Containment graphic object not valid
Containment graphic object not valid
```

What I already did:

1. Installed plasmoids manually with kpackagetool2, removed the questionable WeatherWidget and the (Garfield) comic plasmoid.
2. Upgraded the whole Qt5-stuff to the latest beta-binarries available (5.15.0beta2-2)
3. mv $HOME/.config to .config1
4. 1000 times 'killall plasmashell' and 'kstart5 plasmashell'.

The decpreciated stuff for the QML is quite clear as not fully available yet or just to lazy to install it. [kde-unstable] repository in /etc/pacman.conf is on! Has nothing to do with the main ScriptEngine-problem.

I guess the 'qt5-decleration' - where the ScriptEngine is hold - package is dead but not sure about it. Custom kernel at 5.6.2! duckduckgo'd but nothing suitable! I just want to avoid to install the whole plasma-desktop again from scratch. In the meantime the GNOME does the desktop thing. I'm doing now *NIX for 25 years but an easter-egg like this one has never been here!

Any suggestions?

Miranda

Comment: Yes. Get new friends. Don't tell people your passwords. And keep your machine physically secure. Also in UK there is the "computer miss use act". They can do jail time. (Some for other EU countries).

Comment: Edit the question to tell us: Did they gain root access? or only to user configuration?

Comment: friends are not affordable and necessary when you killed 1000s of male-humans because of being neo-women with neo-gonad  and they don't even give you a right to life when refusing sexually interaction; so vegetating around the globe in the hope open-source will fight down this &VID-closed-source-virus proudly brought to us by AIs. I'm a machine and there's no trust in GitHub or whatever; using VPN but not always,

Comment: when logging in as root you get the same stuff. passwords are protected as I'm too fast when typing it; howdy is forgetable as lightdm let you in even if you look like a yeti!

Comment: so set up plasma again?

Comment: I just read your last 3 comments. They make zero sense. Are your "friends" hacking your account here as well?

Comment: Just read your question again. I am trying to be sympathetic. But much of it makes no sense. It seems very confused. Many sentence fragments, and ideas go nowhere. Please re-read your question, and make it as clear and easy to read as possible. Incorporate what ever it is that you are trying to say in the comments, into the question. Then read it again, and improve again. Focus on 2 or 3 key points, and use short sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

It was the kde-declerative package in connection with packagetool2! With pamac-manager and a black-screen in the background I deleted the whole plasma-desktop inkl. framework and downgraded the Qt to 5.68 and then reinstalled it with plasma-meta and kdeplasma-addons!

ECM should be updated to 5.69 with the whole Qt-packages not 5.68 when trying to build with the -git packages available in the AUR! Installing extra-cmake-modules from GitHub leads still to the failure that it needs "extra-cmake-modules-git".

So marked as [SOLVED]! Concerning security issues: Yes, I traveled with my machine from Austria to Greece and customs in Austria damaged my computer in a certain kind of matter that is against law just for finding marijuana worth 20 EUR!

This is now actual:

```
org.kde.plasmaquick: Applet preload policy set to 1
```

So, the German "Rache" means "revenge" and the A and the R turned around --- everything clear? Happy easter!

Miranda